# NSDate and SQLite3

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdate

I'm having a very annoying issue with my app.
Let's have a sqlite3 database and a datetime column in a table named "daily".

```
- (BOOL)eatQuantity:(NSNumber *)quantity date:(NSDate *)date
{
    User *usr = [User loadCurrentUser];

    BOOL ret;
    sqlite3 *db;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormatter release];

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO daily (id_user, id_food, quantity, date) VALUES (%d, %d, %f, '%@')", usr.idPk.intValue, self.idPk.intValue, quantity.floatValue, strDate];
    NSLog(@"Query: %@", query);
```

When I call this method passing a NSDate object from a UIDatePicker, some user are facing a strange behavior with NSDate, they log this on their console:

Query: INSERT INTO daily (id_user, id_food, quantity, date) VALUES (1, 1010, 130.000000, '2011-12-21 01:20:09 m.')

But the sqlite3 is unable to store a date is a such format like that with the ending "m." string. And users can't view any records because of the null date in the WHERE clause.

So where that "m." comes from? What does it mean? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

don't use NSDateFormatter it will slow down your app massively.

You should use a unix timestamp (1970).
Like this `sqlite3_bind_double(statement, index, [dateObject timeIntervalSince1970]);`

retrieving:

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:doubleValueFromDatabase];
```

Comment: +1 I'm not sure where the `m.` is coming from, but this would probably be better.  Alternatively, you could explicitly set the locale of the `NSDateFormatter` to guarantee that it would generate the same style string regardless of what the user's current locale is.

Comment: I need to use NSDateFormatter because of I store dates in sql's date format. I cannot change the design of my database right now. I'll give a try using nsdateformatter's locale. I'll let you know if it works!